# The aperture size of my camera ( Fujifilm Sx1) is minimun of f11 can i use a filter or something to get images similar to f16 or f22

Tags: aperture, filters

The aperture size of my camera ( Fujifilm Sx1) is minimum of f 11 can i use a filter or something to get images similar to f16 or f22

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Specifically, are you looking for more depth of field or for a longer exposure time?

Answer (score 2):

If you are having problems with exposure being too bright, you can use what is known as an ND filter to reduce the intensity of light reaching the sensor.  Think of it a bit like sunglasses for your camera.  A good ND filter should minimally impact the color of the image but make it overall darker (hence the neutral in neutral density).

Neutral density filters generally give a certain number of stops of light reduction which is equivalent to stops in aperture as well.

Note that this won't change the depth of field any, but no  filter is going to really change your depth of field substantially unless it can also impact the focal length.

Answer (score 1):

**No, nor would you want too.** Most small cameras stop down to F/8 for a reason. The Fuji X-S1 (that's the model I think you have) has a slightly larger sensor which lets aperture go to F/11.

Anything beyond that would *severely* beyond the diffraction limit of the camera and would therefore get images much more blurry. You can blur things in software if you find the images too sharp but there is no way to get more depth-of-field which is truly extensive at those apertures with a small-sensor like the one of the X-S1.

A rough estimate is that shooting af F/11 on the X-S1 is equivalent to shooting at F/48 on a full-frame. You do not see lenses reach those apertures because that would be useless. A much larger sensor is needed which you will find in medium and large format camera who have lenses that reach F/64 and even smaller apertures.